# How to fix "Google couldn't verify this account belongs to you"?

Tags: google-account

O.P.
I switched phones and I cannot login to my account on the new phone. It keeps on giving me the message above.

Weird thing is that I'm still login in my Samsung tabtet. I was able to get some code to verify my identity but I was never asked for this. I was never asked to verify using my phone or Google authenticator either.

The best I got from the AWESOME Google customer service is that they'll get back to me in 3-5 days.

Any ideas on what else to do?